# Error with OAuth2 and Google Sheet Add-ons

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

**Context**

I've developed a Google Workspace Add-on for Gmail and Google Sheets that lets its users interact with their business tools (CRM, Helpdesk, ...) directly within the Google Workspace ecosystem.

In order to interact with third-party services, I need to authenticate the user to those external services using the OAuth2 standard.
For that, I'm using the [apps-script-oauth2](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) library [recommended by Google](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/oauth20-library).

**Issue**

When the user starts the OAuth2 flow in the Add-on side-bar from **Gmail** – everything works perfectly fine:

1. The user hits "Authorize"
2. He is redirected to the external service ABC and grant access to the Google Add-on
3. The service ABC redirects the user to `https://script.google.com/macros/d/{script_id}/usercallback`
4. The access token is retrieved and stored properly

**BUT**
when the user starts the exact same OAuth2 flow in the Add-on side-bar from **Google Sheets** – there is an issue with the callback:

1. The user hits "Authorize" – *OK*
2. He is redirected to the external service ABC and grant access to the Google Add-on – *OK*
3. The service ABC redirects the user to `https://script.google.com/macros/d/{script_id}/usercallback` – *OK*
4. **KO:** Google Script return the following message: "Google Docs encountered an error. [...]" and if I open the console I see a **500** error from Google Server.

**Investigation**

I've tried for the past 3 days to see what changed between the 2 flows – depending on when it is started from **Gmail** and when started from **Google Sheets**.
From my numerous tests, what seems to cause the **500 error** might be linked to the `state` parameter, once returned to the `https://script.google.com/macros/d/{script_id}/usercallback/` redirect URI **(step 4)**.
This `state` token is initially generated at the **step 1** of the flow by the `ScriptApp.newStateToken().withMethod(callbackFunction)` function.

But I couldn't go any further in my exploration, as the **error 500** prevent any `console.log` to go throw, so I'm blind here...

Comment: Hard to troubleshott without seeing your code, especially the calls to Google Docs that trigger the error.

Comment: Hi Ziganotschka! I was coding an example for you and it seems that this issue has been fixed. Even on my initial code – I haven't done any changes on that front and I don't see a 500 anymore  (I'm new on stack overflow, not sure how and if I should archive this post?)

Comment: 500 errors are often a temporarily nature and caused by problems in the background (not you). You don't need to archive his post - instead you can provide an answer explaining that the error was temporarily so other users who encounter the same issue will have this knowledge.